# Slide up section to replace existing div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not too sure if this count as a parallax effect.  Essentially, I have two sections

```
<section class="bg-primary" id="placeholder"></section>

<section class="bg-primary" id="about"></section>
```

Each section has a height of 100%, so it essentially fills the viewport.  What I am trying to achieve is this - initially the section with an id called placeholder is displayed.  When I scroll down, I want the about section to start sliding up to essentially replace the placeholder.  When I reach the bottom, the screen should only display one section, so the about section should basically be layered on top of the placeholder.  If I then scroll the other way, it would start reappearing again.

I have set up a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n4p9hknu/3/) which sets everything up, I have not added any JQuery yet as I am not too sure as to how I can achieve this effect.

Any advice appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: That JSFiddle works exactly how you've described - you scroll down and #about starts sliding up and replaces the view entirely, when you scroll up the opposite happens.

Comment: That is just one div under the other.  The way I am trying to get it is that when you scroll down, the #about div replaces the placeholder, so you end up with only a single div essentially

Comment: Are you instead seeking an animation from jquery that slides the #about div up and replaces it on a single scroll down action?

Comment: Not exactly, just as you slide down it replaces it.